# no value returned from EditText .getText() method

Tags: android

I am stuck with a simple problem of getting text from editText.

```
fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder placeLLDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(PlacesActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_add_dialog, null);
    placeLLDialog.setView(R.layout.place_add_dialog);

    final EditText place = view.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
    final EditText lati = view.findViewById(R.id.placeLati);
    final EditText longi = view.findViewById(R.id.placeLongi);
    placeLLDialog.setTitle("Add Place with Latitude and Longitude")
      .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Helloooo" + place.getText().toString());

          if(!place.getText().toString().equals("") &&
             !lati.getText().toString().equals("") &&
             !longi.getText().toString().equals("")) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Hello" + place.getText().toString());
               final Places places = new Places(place.getText().toString(),
                 lati.getText().toString(), longi.getText().toString());
               mPlacesViewModel.insert(places);
          }
          closeFABMenu();
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
      .show();
  }
```

When I am doing this, I am not getting the value of place, lati and longi, 
i.e. "place.getText().toString()" is empty.

Can anybody kindly help me with this strange problem?

Comment: Replace `placeLLDialog.setView(R.layout.place_add_dialog);` to  `placeLLDialog.setView(view)`;

Comment: hi, thanks. this is the solution. But I don't understand the deference (I am new to java). So, would you like to expand it as an answer?

Comment: Its simple the `view` you are using to get  `Edittext` is never part of `AlertDialog` cause you have never set it to `AlertDialog`. `setView()` is overloaded method you just missed the correct one . That's it.

Comment: but I have added `R.layout.place_add_dialog`, which is the view itself.
isnt it like noun and pronoun?

Comment: That's where the problem is . It will set a new view to the `AlertDialog` i.e a new object . And the view `Object` you are working with is never set to `Dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating the view here:

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_add_dialog, null);
```

but you are not using it just one line after:

```
placeLLDialog.setView(R.layout.place_add_dialog);
```

So you should be setting:

```
placeLLDialog.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder placeLLDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlacesActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_add_dialog,null);
                placeLLDialog.setView(view);
                final EditText place=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
                final EditText lati = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.placeLati);
                final EditText longi = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.placeLongi);
                placeLLDialog.setTitle("Add Place with Latitude and Longitude")
                        .setPositiveButton("Add", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Helloooo" + place.getText().toString());
                                if(!place.getText().toString().equals("") && !lati.getText().toString().equals("") && !longi.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Hello" + place.getText().toString());
                                    final Places places = new  Places(place.getText().toString(),lati.getText().toString(), longi.getText().toString()); 
                                    mPlacesViewModel.insert(places);
                                }
                                closeFABMenu();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .show();
            }
        });
```